# declaring variables using for loop using javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, object, for-loop, assignment-operator

I am trying to declare variables using `for` loop and then test if the **cols** and **rols** are the same.  If they are, it will run a recursive function.  However, I am having trouble doing do in javascript.  Can anyone help?

Right now, it says unexpected variable `==` when comparing `col.1` and `col.2`.  I also tried `col+j` inside the `for` loop, but it was `invalid left-hand side assignment`

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var col = {};
  col.i = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
  col.i = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
}

if (col.1 == col.2 && row.1 == row.2) {
  return this.getRandomBlock();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You should declare `col` and `row`, you declare only `col`.
2. You should declare `col` and `row` outside of the loop, now it declares each time when the body of the loop executes.
3. You assign to `col.i` twice.
4. When you write `col.i` it is equel to `col['i']`, so you should use brackets instead.
5. You don't need object (`{}`), use array (`[]`).
6. You cannot write `col.1` it is not legal, number after dot is not legal, use `col[1]`.
7. You have `0` and `1`, not `1` and `2`.

.

```
var col = [];
var row = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  col[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
  row[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
}

if (col[0] == col[1] && row[0] == row[1]) {
  return this.getRandomBlock();
}
```

Comment: Great Speransky.I just writing down the same.

Answer (score 0):

The **col** variable has declared inside the `for` loop which means that variable instantiated every iteration. So, at the end of the `for` loop, the **col** variable has only one property that is *1 (col.1)*.

After the loop you are trying to access **col.2** which is not a property of **col** object. Also, if you are trying to access col object using `for` loop iteration variable (i or j) the same problem occurs because the value of *i or j* after iteration is *2*

Try the below it will work like a pro.

```
var col = {};
var row = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  col.i = Math.floor(Math.random() * cols);
  row.i = Math.floor(Math.random() * rows);
}
if (col.0 == col.1 && row.0 == row.1) {
  return this.getRandomBlock();
}
```